# Correct way to get the file path of the currently opened project in NetBeans

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans

In NetBeans I want to get correct way to get the file path of the currently opened project. I need it for creating a plugin to NetBeans. I need to acquire the path by querying or by using any commands in command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [org.netbeans.api.project.ui.OpenProjects](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectuiapi/org/netbeans/api/project/ui/OpenProjects.html).

Take note that there can be more than one project opened at a time and also read the "Warning" part in the `OpenProjects` documentation for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the file path, use this:

```
TopComponent activeTC = TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated();
DataObject dataLookup = activeTC.getLookup().lookup(DataObject.class);
String filePath = FileUtil.toFile(dataLookup.getPrimaryFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

That will give you the path for the file that is currently selected.

If you want to get the path of the Main Project, you can use this: (taken from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090681/retrieving-location-of-currently-opened-file-or-project-in-netbeans/16090901?noredirect=1#16090901))

```
Lookup lookup = Utilities.actionsGlobalContext(); 
Project project = lookup.lookup(Project.class);
FileObject projectDir = project.getProjectDirectory();
String projectLocation = projectDir.getPath();
```

The issue using this is that unless you've explicitly selected a given project right before running this code, it does not see any project as the main project.

Therefore, after setting the project with `Project project = lookup.lookup(Project.class);`, I would check to see if it is null, and if it is, use the first block of code above to get the current file path instead.