# Retrieving location of currently opened file or project in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, custom-controls, project

I'm using a custom button in netbeans that references a file in the open project. However, I'm having an issue retrieving the location of that file based upon the open project.
Therefore, I need something that can return the location of the project I'm working in or the location of the file I'm working with.
In essence, I need to be able to call

```
String projectLocation = methodOrVarToGetOpenProjectLocation();
```

I can't use the current directory, because the plugin that I've created with the button doesn't live in the same place as the project I'm working in.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the Project directory like so:

```
Lookup lookup = Utilities.actionsGlobalContext(); 
Project project = lookup.lookup(Project.class);
FileObject projectDir = project.getProjectDirectory();
String projectLocation = projectDir.getPath();
```

The classes are all from the NetBeans API: [`Utilities`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/Utilities.html), [`Lookup`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util-lookup/org/openide/util/Lookup.html), [`Project`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectapi/org/netbeans/api/project/Project.html), and [`FileObject`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/FileObject.html)

If you don't want to just use the current Project you can use the [`OpenProjects`](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.3/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectuiapi/org/netbeans/api/project/ui/OpenProjects.html) class.  You can get the first open Project as follows:

```
Project project = OpenProjects.getDefault().getOpenProjects()[0];
```

Depending on what your button does it might make sense to use [the Main Project](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-main):

```
Project mainProject = OpenProjects.getDefault().getMainProject();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, except one thing... How do I tell it to select the first open project if no project is currently selected? Right now, it fails to work unless a project is explicitly selected.

Comment: @JoshJohnson - Added code showing you how to get the first open Project and also the Main Project.

Comment: Thanks much! I actually tried using the [...].getMainProject(); yesterday when I was doing research, however it has the same issue as the first code: Unless you click on a project name directly before clicking on the button, it doesn't see that project as being the main project. For example, if you edit a file in the project and then click the button, it doesn't consider any project to be the "Main" project. Every time, the Project Name must be clicked on to be considered "Main". Any thoughts on how to get the location or project of the current file being edited?

Comment: I was able to get the file from: TopComponent activeTC = TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated(); DataObject dataLookup = activeTC.getLookup().lookup(DataObject.class); String fileLocation = FileUtil.toFile(dataLookup.getPrimaryFile()).getAbsolutePath();   So I'll use that in the case that a project isn't selected. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @JoshJohnson - To set the Main Project, right click a Project and select *Set as Main Project* in the menu.

Comment: I want this to be as user-friendly as possible, so I don't want them to have to go through the process of selecting a Main Project. I just want the last project that they worked on to be assumed as the main project, which getting the file location does in most instances.

Comment: And where can I find or download this api? I really need for this.

Answer (score 1):

Dave Webb's answer above took care of getting the project location. However, there was an issue in that if the project desired wasn't selected directly before clicking the button, it would not consider that project to be the main project.
For example, doing an edit in the file and then clicking the button would no longer find the project, because the project name was not the last thing clicked.
I found some code that grabbed the open file name:

```
TopComponent activeTC = TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated();
DataObject dataLookup = activeTC.getLookup().lookup(DataObject.class);
String filePath = FileUtil.toFile(dataLookup.getPrimaryFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

I used this in an if statement in the case of `project` being null (after the second line of his first block of code).

That gives me the path to the file I was working in, and then it took a short amount of working with the string to get the location of the project.